# ECJ перестал читать первый класс в списке

Tags: java, android, консоль, build

Собираю APK через эмулятор терминала Termux прямо на устройстве Android из-за отсутствия нормального ПК. Использую измененный мной скрипт с https://github.com/sdrausty/buildAPKs .

Я решил перенести исходники в папку `./src/main`, чтобы одна ide из маркета нормально проживала проект. Переместил, поправил пути в bash-скрипте. Однако ecj почему-то перестал компилировать первый в списке утилиты find класс OpenGL-скрипта.

[image: Ошибка ECJ]

`$PROJECTDIR` содержит рабочую папку, т.е. `/sdcard/tormentpd/`

Однако cat этот файл спокойно находит и выводит.

[image: Вывод cat]

**Что мне сделать, чтобы компилятор снова увидел и собрал нужный класс?**

Gradle использовать невозможно, ибо запуск Java SE на бюджетном смартфоне - очень быстрый путь к окирпичиванию единственного устройства, поэтому исходный проект с гитхаба пришлось переделывать под скрипт.